# I am getting the error while giving the timezone as IST and CDT other than GMT.Why?

Tags: python, python-requests

We should not change the string strings s1 and s2.I am getting the error while giving the time zone as IST but when it is changed to GMT it is working can I know why it is happening and one more doubt can we compare two different time zones.Please check the code here which i have written.
from datetime import datetime

```
 s1 = 'Oct 06 09:42:21 IST 2020'
 d1 = datetime.strptime(s1, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
 print(d1)

 s2 = 'Oct 06 09:42:26 2020 CDT'
 d2 = datetime.strptime(s2, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')
 print(d2)

 print(d1 < d2)
```

Comment: There is an unspoken assumption here that there exists an agreed set of timezone abbreviations. There isn't one. The I in IST can mean India but it can also mean Ireland or Israel.

Answer (score 1):

You can only enter GMT or UTC when you use `%Z`. You can instead use `%z` and enter the offset in hours.

[image]

Comment: ok then how to compare when other timezones are given?

Comment: if you don't care about dependencies you can use a different module like [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). Otherwise a straightforward bu cumbersome way would be creating a dictionary.